# Finding the probability of a probability density function

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions

Suppose that $f(x) = e^{−x}$ for $0 < x$.

find $P(1 < X)$

I know typically we integrate $f(x)$ from $1$ to $\infty$ but in this case $x = 1$ is not included, how do I go about doing this? All examples I've seen have $<=$ or $>=$ but not $<$ or $>$.

Comment: I guess you mean $f(x)=e^{-x}$ for $x>0$? Note that "$0<x$" is the same thing as "$x>0$".

Comment: Do you know what the probability of a single point for a continuous variable is? I.e., do you know what $P(X=1)$ is?

Comment: isn't the probability of a single point zero?

Comment: Yes. So $P(X>1)=P(X>1)+P(X=1)=P(X\geq 1)$, meaning it does not matter if you use strict inequalities or not.

Answer (score 1):

The probability that $X = 1$ *exactly* is zero for a continuous distribution so $P(X > 1) = P(X \geq 1)$.

With that in mind the answer is simply $$P(X > 1) = \int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-x}dx$$

Comment: alright thank you, that's what i figured but the change in signs had me hesitating.